# About Using Multi Select?

Tags: php, html, select

Hi I'm working on the code now and the ticket system sending a notification to a user that selects him about. 
I want a notification to select more than one user and more than one user.
I tried to use this for Multi Select more than one user selection, again when I say save too, a single user is registering on this can you help me ?

```
<div class="form-group select-placeholder"> 
                        <label for="assigned" class="control-label"> 
                            <?php echo _l('ticket_settings_assign_to'); ?> 
                        </label> 
                        <select name="assigned" id="assigned" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-none-selected-text="<?php echo _l('dropdown_non_selected_tex'); ?>" data-width="100%"> 
                            <option value=""><?php echo _l('ticket_settings_none_assigned'); ?></option> 
                            <?php foreach($staff as $member){ ?> 
                                <option value="<?php echo $member['staffid']; ?>" <?php if($member['staffid'] == get_staff_user_id()){echo '';} ?>> 
                                    <?php echo $member['firstname'] . ' ' . $member['lastname'] ; ?> 
                                </option> 
                            <?php } ?> 
                        </select> 
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to select multiple you have to add the multiple attribute to the  box.

```
<select multiple>
```

To receive the values in your code as an array you should change the `name` from `name="assigned"` to `name="assigned[]"`

This will send the multi selected data back as an array to PHP or whichever language you are using

```
<select multiple name="assigned[]" id="assigned" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-none-selected-text="<?php echo _l('dropdown_non_selected_tex'); ?>" data-width="100%">
```

Comment: IIRC if you don't name the input on the html side using the PHP array brackets `[]` you will only get the last entry selected

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the `multiple` attribute in your `<select>` tag.

---

**Note**: The javascript there is used to avoid holding the ctrl-key while selecting multiple options.

```js
  window.onmousedown = function (e) {
  var el = e.target;
  if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'option' && el.parentNode.hasAttribute('multiple')) {
      e.preventDefault();

      // toggle selection
      if (el.hasAttribute('selected')) el.removeAttribute('selected');
      else el.setAttribute('selected', '');

      // hack to correct buggy behavior
      var select = el.parentNode.cloneNode(true);
      el.parentNode.parentNode.replaceChild(select, el.parentNode);
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="option-list" size="5" multiple>
            <option value="option-1">Option</option>
            <option value="option-2">Option</option>
            <option value="option-3">Option</option>
            <option value="option-4">Option</option>
            <option value="option-5">Option</option>
            <option value="option-6">Option</option>
            <option value="option-7">Option</option>
            <option value="option-8">Option</option>
            <option value="option-9">Option</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I organized the code this way. But I couldn't get a successful result.

```
<div class="form-group select-placeholder">
                        <label for="assigned" class="control-label">
                            <?php echo _l('ticket_settings_assign_to'); ?>
                        </label>
                        <select multiple name="assigned[]" id="assigned" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-none-selected-text="<?php echo _l('dropdown_non_selected_tex'); ?>" data-width="100%"> 
                            <option value=""><?php echo _l('ticket_settings_none_assigned'); ?></option>
                            <?php foreach($staff as $member){ ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $member['staffid']; ?>" <?php if($member['staffid'] == get_staff_user_id()){echo '';} ?>>
                                    <?php echo $member['firstname'] . ' ' . $member['lastname'] ; ?>
                                </option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
```